# trying to make clone of spotify app getting error in localhost:3000 TYPEERROR: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using stackoverflow for the first time and I dont know its rules and regulation so I apologies for any of my mistakes.

I am trying to make a clone of spotify with react. While I was making everything was good but after I complete coding found an ERROR in the localhost:3000
{TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined}

Error must in these line I try finding but I didn't found.

**App.js**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import SpotifyWebApi from "spotify-web-api-js";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import Player from "./Player";
import { getTokenFromResponse } from "./spotify";
import "./App.css";
import Login from "./Login";

const s = new SpotifyWebApi();

function App() {
  const [{ token }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Set token
    const hash = getTokenFromResponse();
    window.location.hash = "";
    let _token = hash.access_token;

    if (_token) {
      s.setAccessToken(_token);

      dispatch({
        type: "SET_TOKEN",
        token: _token,
      });

      s.getPlaylist("37i9dQZEVXcJZyENOWUFo7").then((response) =>
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_DISCOVER_WEEKLY",
          discover_weekly: response,
        })
      );

      s.getMyTopArtists().then((response) =>
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_TOP_ARTISTS",
          top_artists: response,
        })
      );

      dispatch({
        type: "SET_SPOTIFY",
        spotify: s,
      });

      s.getMe().then((user) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user,
        });
      });

      s.getUserPlaylists().then((playlists) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_PLAYLISTS",
          playlists,
        });
      });
    }
  }, [token, dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {!token && <Login />}
      {token && <Player spotify={s} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Header.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Header.css";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import { Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function Header({ spotify }) {
  const [{ user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="header__left">
        <SearchIcon />
        <input
          placeholder="Search for Artists, Songs, or Podcasts "
          type="text"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="header__right">
        <Avatar alt={user?.display_name} src={user?.images[0].url} />
        <h4>{user?.display_name}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

export default App;

Answer (score 0):

From the App.js file,
You forgot to add the actions during dispatch from the reducer.

**Your snippet**

```
s.getMe().then((user) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user,
        });
      });

      s.getUserPlaylists().then((playlists) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_PLAYLISTS",
          playlists,
        });
      });
```

**Suggested solution**

```
s.getMe().then((user) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: user,
        });
      });

      s.getUserPlaylists().then((playlists) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_PLAYLISTS",
          playlists: playlists,
        });
      });
```

I hope it solves your issue.